# How i can send delete request for to delete video in AJAX, its returning 204 status

Tags: ajax, api, coldfusion, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to delete my vimeo video by using AJAX request but its always returning 204 status code, and video is not deleting from account. Here is code example.

```
$(".js-delete").click(function(){
    var videoID = $(this).data("target");// /videos/2332
    $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         url: "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos",
         headers: {
           "Authorization": "bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         },
         data: {
            url: "https://api.vimeo.com/me"+videoID,
            method: "DELETE"
         },
         dataType: "json"
         success: function(response){
            console.log(response); //will print the whole JSON
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Request Failed.');
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone please suggest some changes required for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks much for your reply, i have tried both way but couldn't get any positive response, can you please suggest me some better way in ajax request for remove video?

Comment: Or, have you any idea about vimeo library in coldfusion, I don't want to use any other Language like php etc.

thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with vimeo, but the [delete example in the documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#delete_video) looks different than yours, `DELETE https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}`.  What happens if you do a DELETE with that URL (keep the authorization  headers but remove the `data`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending

- a HTTP `POST`
- to the URL `https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`
- with the Bearer token as a `header`

  - Note that [it should be](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) `Bearer <token>` (uppercase **B**), not `bearer <token>`.
- with a data packet that contains another URL and HTTP method.

But according to the Vimeo API docs to [Delete a Video](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#delete_video), the request should be

```
DELETE https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}
```

with a note:

> This method requires a token with the "delete" scope.

A jQuery ajax request should look something like this if the bearer token is correct:

```
$(".js-delete").click(function(){
    var videoID = $(this).data("target");// /videos/2332
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/' + videoID,
        headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response); //will print the whole JSON
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Request Failed.');
        }
    });
});
```

You should be able to test this request using https://www.getpostman.com/ to verify the request and bearer token works outside of your CF app.